# How to get image to show on top of header image

Tags: wordpress, z-index

I gave my sidebar a negative top margin to display an image over top of the header yellow image but I can't get the sidebar image to show on top. I have added position: relative and played with the z-index but nothing is working.

Here is the [page](https://www.lendinghearts.org/recipes/festive-napa-cabbage-salad-with-ginger-garlic-poppyseed-dressing/)

Here's the css code I have -

```
.reciperight {
float: right;
width: 28%;
color: #512e70 !important;
font-size: 18px !important;
position: relative;
margin-top: -200px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I checked your page and there is a CSS code in your parent `#primay` div that makes the image hidden.
change the overflow from `hidden to visible` and your issue will fix like bellow.

```
#primary {
        float: left;
        overflow: visible;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! That fixed it!! I knew it was going to be something so easy but couldn't find!!  LOL

Comment: @Peggy if it has solved your problem, make it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#primary {
float: left;
/* overflow: hidden; */
width: 100%;
```

}

If you use `overflow:hidden` then it was hidden outside of content so remove `overflow:hidden`.